# YouTube embed API: The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I'm embedding some YouTube videos on my website. I've been getting a few complaints that they don't load up. I investigated and noticed that when attempting to play them, I get a few 403 Forbidden errors:

[image: 403]

Taking a look at the JSON response I get a few messages that generally say "The caller does not have permission". Here is the full JSON data:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The caller does not have permission",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? I didn't think I needed a key or token to embed YouTube videos. What is the cause of this? Has my IP addresses been banned from a Google API?

For reference, the ID of the video I tried to load was `Sq9kl3ybqY0`.

Comment: the same problem.
have you tried opening your website with a smartphone? or using the incognito browser? I have tried it on smartphones and incognito browsers and the results work. I suspect this is because of the browser extension I installed correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I have this problem personally with every Youtube embed video I try to play the past week. Same error. I don't understand why

Comment: Same issue for us, but the issue is inconsistent, sometimes it works and others it fails with the errors above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fix will be to replace the URL from youtube with the embed URL.
Eg. If you have used a URL like youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID then replace it with the embed URL like youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID

Generally, this error occurs when your embed is initially hidden. In this case, just add `?html5=1` to embed the URL.